# if/else condition defines variable. undefined: dat (variable)

Tags: variables, go, static

I know this is a basic question, but I'm curious why the code below does not work. There is no use case where this variable would not be declared.

```
if (bundled == "true") {
            dat, err := Asset("index.html")
        } else {
            dat, err := ioutil.ReadFile("./index.html")

        }
        if ( err != nil) {
            os.Exit(0)
        }

        t, _ = t.Parse(string(dat))
        p := Person{Scope: ""}
        t.Execute(w, p)
```

I get the error

```
.\run.go:262: undefined: dat
```

I'm sure it's just basic GOLANG stuff I'm still learning.

Thanks for your support

Comment: `if-else` blocks have their own scope. `dat` is not visible outside of them. You can declare `var dat []byte` before `if (bundled == "true")` to fix it. Read: [Declaration scopes in Go](https://dave.cheney.net/2016/12/15/declaration-scopes-in-go)

Comment: How could a declare dat in such a way that I could complete this request. Is there a way to create a place holder. I didn't realize the if/else were in their own space. Interesting

Comment: declare the variables in the scope you want. For reference: https://golang.org/ref/spec#Declarations_and_scope

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`if-else` blocks have their own scope. In your case `dat`is not visible outside of them.

You can declare `var dat []byte` before `if (bundled == "true")` to fix it.

Docs: https://golang.org/ref/spec#Declarations_and_scope

You may also want to read: [Declaration scopes in Go](https://dave.cheney.net/2016/12/15/declaration-scopes-in-go)

Comment: Okay, I got it to compile, see if it works. I had to declare this beforehand      dat:= []byte{}

Comment: It's recommended to prefer `var dat []byte` over `dat := []byte{}`.  Main reason is that the former defines a _nil_ slice while the latter defines an _empty_ slice.  Not only does this make checking the slice easier, but it avoids allocating the slice until you append something to it (and in this case, you'd just be throwing away the original allocation anyway).  Also, you'll want to declare the `err` variable beforehand and completely eliminate the short-form assignment in the if statement, or you'll just end up masking the `dat` variable instead.

Comment: @Kaedys `@dat := []byte{}` does not allocate memory.

Comment: `dat := []byte{}` has identical effect to `dat := make([]byte, 0).  It doesn't allocate any space, but it *does* assign an address to the pointer in the slice header (pointing to a 0-length array that takes up no memory).  This is, technically, more expensive than simply creating the slice header itself, and is also useless, since `append()` still has to make a new array on the first call anyway.  It's also uglier, but that's just me.  Also, `dat == nil` is only true for the `var` version.  Lastly, `golint` specifically checks for and complains about empty literals like that.

Comment: The major use case for an empty slice (either empty literal or `make([]type, 0)`, though the latter is preferred) is if the program is returning the slice (directly, or as part of a larger data structure) via an API encoding system like JSON or Thrift or some such.  In those cases, a `nil` slice is encoded as `null` in most encodings, while an empty slice is encoded as `[ ]` (or the equivalent in whatever encoding you're using).