# How to declare a SQL row, if else statement not declared problem

Tags: go

I have a code like this below.

```
var sql string

if pnt.Type == "newType" {
    sql = `select code, count(*) count from ( 
                select code 
                    from code_table 
                    where start >= ? and end <= ? 
                union 
                select code 
                    from code_table 
                    where start >= ? and end <= ? 
                ) a group by code`
    rows, err := pnt.readConn("testdb").Query(sql, start, end, start, end)
} else {
    sql = `select code, count(*) count from code_table where start >= ? and end <= ?` group by code
    rows, err := pnt.readConn("testdb").Query(sql, start, end)
}

if err == nil {
    defer rows.Close()
    for rows.Next() {
        var code, count int
        rows.Scan(&code, &count)
    }
} else {
    log.Println(err)
}
```

This will give me an error something like this "Variable not declared for rows, err"...

I've tried declaring "var err error" and within the if else statement, I use = instead of :=
something like this

```
var err error
rows, err = pnt.switchConn("base", "read").Query(sql, start, end)
```

However, I still can't declare the rows cuz I will have different kind of errors for that. I tried declaring it as string but no luck.

This is my first time using golang and the if else thing is giving me a hard time, why can't I just use := inside if else statement. As you can see, I can't use rows, err := outside the if else statement, cuz both have different numbers of parameters.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Variable not declared, inside a if..else statement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21481288/variable-not-declared-inside-a-if-else-statement), [if/else condition defines variable. undefined: dat (variable)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42074611/if-else-condition-defines-variable-undefined-dat-variable)

Comment: i;ve search from others but couldn't solve the rows problem, I couldn't declare rows until someone show me the solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are facing issues because of the scope of the variable.
In Golang, `:=` creates a new variable inside a scope.

`rows, err := pnt.ReadConn("testdb").Query(sql, start, end, start, end)`

Creates a new `rows` and `err` variables in the `if` block which won't be accessible outside the if block.

[Shorthand declarations in Go](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Short_variable_declarations)

The fix,

```
var sql string
var err error
var rows *sql.Rows

if pnt.Type == "newType" {
    sql = `select code, count(*) count from ( 
                select code 
                    from code_table 
                    where start >= ? and end <= ? 
                union 
                select code 
                    from code_table 
                    where start >= ? and end <= ? 
                ) a group by code`
    rows, err = pnt.ReadConn("testdb").Query(sql, start, end, start, end)
} else {
    sql = `select code, count(*) count from code_table where start >= ? and end <= ?` group by code
    rows, err = pnt.ReadConn("testdb").Query(sql, start, end)
}

if err == nil {
    defer rows.Close()
    for rows.Next() {
        var code, count int
        rows.Scan(&code, &count)
    }
} else {
    log.Println(err)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In golang ":=" mean you declare a variable and assign them a this value GO will automatically detect his type so : 
Exemples 
`variable := 15` 
It’s the same 
`var variable int = 15`

So when you do this `rows, err := pnt.switchConn("base", "read").Query(sql, start, end, start, end)
} else {
    sql =`select code, count(*) count from code_table where start >= ? and end <= ?`group by code
    rows, err := pnt.switchConn("base", "read").Query(sql, start, end)
}`

You declare the same variable rows and err twice